# Optimizing filter sizes of CNN with Optuna

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, optuna

I have created a CNN for classification of three classes based on input images of size `39 x 39`. I'm optimizing the parameters of the network using Optuna. For Optuna I'm defining the following parameters to optimize:

```
num_blocks = trial.suggest_int('num_blocks', 1, 4)
num_filters = [int(trial.suggest_categorical("num_filters", [32, 64, 128, 256]))]
kernel_size = trial.suggest_int('kernel_size', 2, 7)
num_dense_nodes = trial.suggest_categorical('num_dense_nodes', [64, 128, 256, 512, 1024])
dense_nodes_divisor = trial.suggest_categorical('dense_nodes_divisor', [1, 2, 4, 8])
batch_size = trial.suggest_categorical('batch_size', [16, 32, 64, 128])
drop_out = trial.suggest_discrete_uniform('drop_out', 0.05, 0.5, 0.05)
lr = trial.suggest_loguniform('lr', 1e-6, 1e-1)

dict_params = {'num_blocks': num_blocks,
 'num_filters': num_filters,
 'kernel_size': kernel_size,
 'num_dense_nodes': num_dense_nodes,
 'dense_nodes_divisor': dense_nodes_divisor,
 'batch_size': batch_size,
 'drop_out': drop_out,
 'lr': lr}
```

My network looks as follows:

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(39,39,3))

# 1st cnn block
x = Conv2D(filters=dict_params['num_filters'],
 kernel_size=dict_params['kernel_size'],
 strides=1, padding='same')(input_tensor)
x = BatchNormalization()(x, training=training)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(padding='same')(x)
x = Dropout(dict_params['drop_out'])(x)

# additional cnn blocks
for i in range(1, dict_params['num_blocks']):
    x = Conv2D(filters=dict_params['num_filters']*(2**i), kernel_size=dict_params['kernel_size'], strides=1, padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x, training=training)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(padding='same')(x)
    x = Dropout(dict_params['drop_out'])(x)

# mlp
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(dict_params['num_dense_nodes'], activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(dict_params['drop_out'])(x)
x = Dense(dict_params['num_dense_nodes'] // dict_params['dense_nodes_divisor'], activation='relu')(x)
output_tensor = Dense(self.number_of_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

# instantiate and compile model
cnn_model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=output_tensor)
opt = Adam(lr=dict_params['lr'])
loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'
cnn_model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy',  tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])
```

I'm optimizing (minimizing) the validation loss with Optuna. There is a maximum of 4 blocks in the network and the number of filters is doubled for each block. That means e.g. 64 in the first block, 128 in the second block, 256 in the third and so on. There are two problems. First, when we start with e.g. 256 filters and a total of 4 blocks, in the last block there will be 2048 filters which is too much.

Is it possible to make the `num_filters` parameter dependent on the `num_blocks` parameter? That means if there are more blocks, the starting filter size should be smaller. So, for example, if `num_blocks` is chosen to be 4, `num_filters` should only be sampled from 32, 64 and 128.

Second, I think it is common to double the filter size but there are also networks with constant filter sizes or two convolutions (with same number of filters) before a max pooling layer (similar to VGG) and so on. Is it possible to adapt the Optuna optimization to cover all these variations?